# How to get 1 field of the output of a DOS script?

Tags: ms-dos

I have a DOS script get_resolution.bat. This writes out the resolution info of an image file. Eg:

```
>get_resolution.bat image_file.jpg
Resolution = 400 x 400 DPI
```

Now I need the 3th field, the horizontal resolution, of that output, being 400.

In the calling script `get_horizontal.bat`I must store that field in an environment variable, and echo that environment variable to the output. So, this should work as follows:

```
>get_horizontal_resolution.bat image_file.jpg
400
```

How can I do that? I need that in native DOS.

Comment: Is that the DPI or the resolution? It would seem to be an odd resolution (square screen).

Comment: That is the resolution expressed in dpi. It are very large files. I could have 600x600 with that scanner. Unfortionatly, the memory of that scanner was insufficient for the large image. So the resolution needed to be restricted to 400x400 dpi.

Comment: No, DPI is pitch. Resolution is how many on the screen.

Comment: On my scanner I can generate 600x600dpi images. In that case for the genrated image files:

Comment: Right, the pitch is 600x600. The resolution is how many total dots across and down the page. For example, a screen resolution could be 1024x764 with a pitch of 96 DPI.

Comment: I wrote resolution because the program that is called in `get_resolution.bat` (Irfanview), generates something which outputs eg `Resolution = 600 x 600 DPI`. But that is not the problem. The problem is to catch the ASCII output of `get_resolution.bat` and then pick the 3th field. out of that.

Comment: `@echo off
for /F usebackq^ delims^= ^ tokens^=3 %%G in (
  `get_resolution.bat image_file.jpg`
) do (
  echo %%G
  set /a "SomeENVvar=%%G"
)`

Comment: this doesn't work. I cant figure out why.FOR /F "usebackq delims=  tokens=3" %%I IN ( `get_resolution.bat %1` ) DO SET HOR_RES=%%I
ECHO %HOR_RES%

Comment: This doesn't work. I cant figure out why. `FOR /F "usebackq delims= tokens=3" %%I IN ( get_resolution.bat %1 ) DO SET HOR_RES=%%I ECHO %HOR_RES%